# What happen if disable lease check in jackrabbit oak implementation

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak, jcr-sql2

We are using jackrabbit oak in our application. we are getting below error while processing requests.

```
*"This oak instance failed to update the lease in time and can therefore no longer access this DocumentNodeStore."*
```

Any impact on application process if we disable lease check using jackrabbit oak implementation?
What is significance of lease check?